# How can I encrypt string with DES algorithm in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, des

I have the following shell script which uses openssl to encrypt string:

```
encrypt() {
STRING_TO_BE_ENCRYPTED=$1
DATE_STRING=$2

MD5=$(/bin/echo -n ${DATE_STRING} | openssl md5)
MD5=${MD5#*=\ }

key=${MD5:0:8}
iv=${MD5:24:8}

key=$(/bin/echo -n "${key}" |od -A n -t x1|sed s/\ //g)
iv=$(/bin/echo -n "${iv}" |od -A n -t x1|sed s/\ //g)

/bin/echo -n "${STRING_TO_BE_ENCRYPTED}" | openssl des -e -nosalt -K ${key} -iv ${iv} -a
}
```

I am trying to make the same function in javascript(to use it in postman). At the moment I have the following code:

```
var DATE_STRING = "Tue, 6 Mar 2018 11:47:23 EET";
var STRING_TO_BE_ENCRYPTED = "somestring";

//MD5=$(/bin/echo -n ${DATE_STRING} | openssl md5)
//MD5=${MD5#*=\ }
var MD5 = CryptoJS.MD5(DATE_STRING).toString();

//key=${MD5:0:8}
var key=MD5.substring(0, 8);
//iv=${MD5:24:8}
var iv=MD5.substring(MD5.length - 8);

//key=$(/bin/echo -n "${key}" |od -A n -t x1|sed s/\ //g)
var keyHex = toHex(key);
//iv=$(/bin/echo -n "${iv}" |od -A n -t x1|sed s/\ //g)
var ivHex = toHex(iv);
And the only issue that I have is the last string from my shell script:

// /bin/echo -n "${STRING_TO_BE_ENCRYPTED}" | openssl des -e -nosalt -K ${key} -iv ${iv} -a
```

I completely stuck with encrypting using "des". Could some please help me with converting the last string to javascript?

Comment: First link in ducksuckgo search results: https://gist.github.com/ufologist/5581486 have you seen this?

Comment: I tried to use following string to encrypt: `var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(str, keyHex, { iv: ivHex, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });` but it produces "U2FsdGVkX1+yjTaLLfy0Rr2R6UIKaUzRSfBQg0apKmA=" in JS but in my shell script I receive "V1MyXd643dSUJQ59fPXUBA=="

Comment: **Do not use DES for new work**, it is no longer considered secure and has been superceeded by AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) DES only has key size is only 56 bits which is not considered to be secure, AES supports key sizes of 128,192 and 256 bits. See [Security comparison of DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181/5121).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I played little bit more with my code and now I have the working one:

```
var DATE_STRING = "Tue, 6 Mar 2018 11:47:23 EET";
var str="somestring";
var MD5 = CryptoJS.MD5(DATE_STRING).toString();

var key=MD5.substring(0, 8);
var iv=MD5.substring(MD5.length - 8);    

var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
var ivHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex));

var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(str, keyHex, { iv: ivHex, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });
var result = encrypted.toString();
```

So this code produces the same result as my shell script with openssl